# ClientLoginError UberSDK

Tags: ios, uber-api

I have followed the exact implementation of Uber iOS SDK in my iOS app as mentioned here https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk, and made sure that Callback URI schemes are registered in the uber developer dashboard which i have used in the app. But its throwing UBSDKRidesClientError. Here is my code for the button:

UBSDKRideRequestButton *button = [[UBSDKRideRequestButton alloc] init];

UBSDKRidesClient *ridesClient = [[UBSDKRidesClient alloc] init];

```
__block UBSDKRideParametersBuilder *builder = [[UBSDKRideParametersBuilder alloc] init];
builder = [builder setPickupLocation: pickupLocation];
builder = [builder setDropoffLocation: dropoffLocation];
[ridesClient fetchCheapestProductWithPickupLocation: pickupLocation completion:^(UBSDKUberProduct* _Nullable product, UBSDKResponse* _Nullable response) {

    if (product) {
        builder = [builder setProductID: product.productID];
        button.rideParameters = [builder build];
        [button loadRideInformation];
    }
}];
```

Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without more information on the error, but I would guess that you aren't authorized. Can you check the `.code` of the RidesClientError you get back?

If it is `unauthorized` that means you don't have a valid access token to hit the products / estimates endpoint. Either you need to log in first and get a valid access token OR include the `UberServerToken` entry in your Info.plist with the value of your Server Token (found on the developer dashboard)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for getting back with me.
I just checked its giving me unauthorized error. I have already signed in on Uber app.
I didn't set the UberServerToken in Info.plist because its not mentioned in documentation of Uber SDK. So I have just set the UberServerToken and its working now but one thing is happening, I am already passing pickup and drop of locations as you can see in my above posted code but Uber App not pre filling the destination. Any idea why?

Comment: You need to set a dropoff nickname or formatted address for destination to appear. See discussion here: https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/issues/57

Comment: And to clarify, when I say you need to log in, I mean via the Uber API, not in the actual Uber App

Comment: Hey, just a quick question. Can i change only text color of the Uber Button to Grey?